# Why is $\{a\in\mathbb{Z} \mid 1≤a≤p-1, a^d\equiv 1 \pmod p\}=\cup_{e\mid d}\{a\in\mathbb{Z} \mid 1≤a≤p-1, ord_p(a)=e\}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\{a\in\mathbb{Z} \mid 1≤a≤p-1, a^d\equiv 1 \pmod p\}=\cup_{e\mid d}\{a\in\mathbb{Z} \mid 1≤a≤p-1, ord_p(a)=e\}$

Is there any way to see this immediately/think about it intuitively?

This question was motivated by the proof to the following theorem:

**Theorem**. Let p be prime, $d\in \mathbb Z^+,d|p-1.$ Then the number of values of $a\in\{1,2,...,p-1\}$ with order $d$ is $\varphi(d).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finite groups, every element $x$ has a power $t$ such that $x^t$, is the neutral element of the group. The smallest positive such $t$ is called the order of that element $ord(x)$, and it turns out that every such $t$ is an integer multiple of the order: $x^t=1 \Rightarrow t=f\times ord(x)$ for some integer $f$.

Applied to the multiplicative group mod $p$, the neutral element is obviously $1$.
So, if $a^d \equiv 1 \mod p$ that means $d$ is a multiple of the order of $a$. That's why the right hand part of your equation is a union of over all potential orders, which are exactly the divisors of $d$.

If the first part isn't known to you, then it's relatively straifghtforward to verify it for the multiplicative group mod $p$. For example, say $a^5 \equiv 1 \mod p$ and $5$ is the smallest such value. Then $a^9 \equiv 1 \mod p$ is impossible, as that would imply $a^4 \equiv 1 \mod p$,